# Eliminate QGIS temporary files during Python script

Tags: python, qgis, temporary-files, pyqgis

I am using a loop to create many raster sampling outputs.
After the loop is finished, QGIS takes quite a while to "clean up" the directories where the output files are placed, meaning: It takes time (about 20 minutes) to delete the two temporary files per output Geopackage (all in all 1128x16 files).
I am accessing the raster sampling via the processing.run() function.

```
processing.run("qgis:rastersampling", { 'COLUMN_PREFIX' : 'Month', 'INPUT' : 'C:/File.gpkg', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Output.gpkg', 'RASTERCOPY' : 'C:/Raster.gpkg' })
```

Is it possible to trigger the "clean up" process after each single execution of the raster sampling?
So the user of the script would not wait in front of a freezed screen and ask himself why he has to do so, in regard that all of the desired output files are already created.

Of course, the time to complete the whole algorithm would maybe increase, but it would be much more user friendly :)